# How to measure memory usage from inside a C++ program?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Is it possible, for a c++ program, to track how much memory the program is using at one time?

For example, a function with a prototype:

```
int getEstimatedTotalMemoryUsage();
```

I suppose if it's not possible, then one will have to get out of the program, do a system call and check the results from there. If so, what tools are available for such purposes? Assuming such a thing is possible, that is.

edit: I'm using linux, any tools that can do this for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes - use POSIX [`getrusage`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrusage.html).  From the [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage):

> #### Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <sys/time.h>
> #include <sys/resource.h>
>
> int getrusage(int who, struct rusage *usage);
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> **`getrusage()`** returns current resource usages, for a *who* of either **`RUSAGE_SELF`** or **`RUSAGE_CHILDREN`**. The former asks for resources used by the current process, the latter for resources used by those of its children that have terminated and have been waited for.
>
> ```
> struct rusage {
>     struct timeval ru_utime; /* user time used */
>     struct timeval ru_stime; /* system time used */
>     long   ru_maxrss;        /* maximum resident set size */
>     long   ru_ixrss;         /* integral shared memory size */
>     long   ru_idrss;         /* integral unshared data size */
>     long   ru_isrss;         /* integral unshared stack size */
>     long   ru_minflt;        /* page reclaims */
>     long   ru_majflt;        /* page faults */
>     long   ru_nswap;         /* swaps */
>     long   ru_inblock;       /* block input operations */
>     long   ru_oublock;       /* block output operations */
>     long   ru_msgsnd;        /* messages sent */
>     long   ru_msgrcv;        /* messages received */
>     long   ru_nsignals;      /* signals received */
>     long   ru_nvcsw;         /* voluntary context switches */
>     long   ru_nivcsw;        /* involuntary context switches */
> };
> ```

Comment: And for GNU/Linux, this is the `struct rusage`: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Resource-Usage.html

Comment: Anything similar for Windows?

Comment: "Not all fields are meaningful under Linux. In Linux 2.4
only the fields ru_utime, ru_stime, ru_minflt, and ru_majflt are main-
tained. Since Linux 2.6, ru_nvcsw and ru_nivcsw are also maintained. "

Comment: Good catch, @Jay - I use `getrusage()` on my mac all the time, and I didn't even think it might not be fully implemented on Linux.  Is there an alternative source of information for the OP?  Clearly I should have read the whole man page...

Comment: Ah, so ixrss, idrss etc which (I'm guessing) would be about memory not implemented on linux?

Comment: Ah, found out it's not working on ubuntu :/ Thanks anyways, will look again

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of measuring memory used by process on Windows.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

// [...]

PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS memCounter;
BOOL result = K32GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &memCounter, sizeof(memCounter));
std::cout << "WorkingSetSize " << memCounter.WorkingSetSize << std::endl;
```

And explanations of returned values https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/psapi/ns-psapi-process_memory_counters

Answer (score 2):

I wanted this today, myself, so sharing the tested results here.  I believe a call to getmem() will do what the OP asked, on any unix box.  Written in very generic C, it will work in C or C++.

```
// Calling function must free the returned result.
char* exec(const char* command) {
  FILE* fp;
  char* line = NULL;
  // Following initialization is equivalent to char* result = ""; and just
  // initializes result to an empty string, only it works with
  // -Werror=write-strings and is so much less clear.
  char* result = (char*) calloc(1, 1);
  size_t len = 0;

  fflush(NULL);
  fp = popen(command, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot execute command:\n%s\n", command);
    return NULL;
  }

  while(getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) {
    // +1 below to allow room for null terminator.
    result = (char*) realloc(result, strlen(result) + strlen(line) + 1);
    // +1 below so we copy the final null terminator.
    strncpy(result + strlen(result), line, strlen(line) + 1);
    free(line);
    line = NULL;
  }

  fflush(fp);
  if (pclose(fp) != 0) {
    perror("Cannot close stream.\n");
  }
  return result;
}

int getmem() {
  pid_t pid = getpid();
  char cmd[64];
  snprintf(cmd, 64, "/bin/ps -p %d -o size", pid);
  char* result = exec(cmd);
  if (!result) {
    return 0;
  }
  // Find first newline.
  int pos = 0;
  while (result[pos] != '\n') {
    pos++;
  }
  // Remove the final newline.
  result[strlen(result) - 1] = '\0';
  // Convert to integer.
  int size = atoi(result + pos + 1);
  free(result);
  return size;
}
```

Technically, I suppose the printf(...) line should be fprintf(stderr, ...), but I tend to have stderr redirected for certain environment-specific logging reasons, and this is how I compiled and tested the code, so I'm copying verbatim to avoid breakage.

Answer (score 1):

Get your PID:    `pid_t getpid(void);    // unistd.h`

Parse `/proc/<id>/smaps`

If you don't care about shared libraries in mem total it may be simpler

make a system call to `ps -p <id>  -o %mem`