# how to calculate the total memory and CPU usage consumed by an application in c++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, cpu-usage

can any one tell me how to calculate the memory and CPU usage consumed by an application while executing.?

Comment: The answer will be platform specific. What platform are you wanting to run on?

Comment: @bames53 : i am running my application in Power pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some great answers probably you are looking for and , some of them you might ask next.! [determine CPU and memory consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63166/977676)