# Practical Usage of Virtual Memory

Tags: memory, virtual

I have used the code

```
MEMORYSTATUSEX memInfo;
memInfo.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memInfo);
DWORDLONG totalVirtualMem = memInfo.ullTotalPageFile;
DWORDLONG virtualMemUsed = memInfo.ullTotalPageFile - memInfo.ullAvailPageFile;
DWORDLONG totalPhysMem = memInfo.ullTotalPhys;
```

provided at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

Output is like:  2.3GB.

```
totalVirtualMem = 8.5 Gb
virtualMemUsed  = 2.3 Gb
totalPhysMem    = 4   Gb
```

Does this means that my program requires 2.3Gb of memory? Could you also comment on total virtual memory and RAM? Also I was not able to run this code:

```
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &pmc, sizeof(pmc));
SIZE_T virtualMemUsedByMe = pmc.PrivateUsage;
```

as it gives error as,

```
error C2664: 'GetProcessMemoryInfo' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX *' to 'PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS'
```

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon exactly the same Problem and found out that a simple type cast solved it for me.

```
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*)&pmc, sizeof(pmc));
SIZE_T virtualMemUsedByMe = pmc.PrivateUsage;
```

The solution is also described [here (msdn: Question about GetProcessMemoryInfo)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/Vsexpressvc/thread/720198c4-04a2-4737-9159-6e23a217d6b7).