# How to detect a process cpu/memory usage and kill it when it exceeds a certain value?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, process, cpu-usage

i'm learning c/c++ and i'm wondering if it is possible to detect a process by it's name and kill it when it's cpu/memory usage exceed a certain value. I would apreciate any help with the actual code or just pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Which language are you using? C or C++?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Yes you can but how you do it will vary depending on the OS

Comment: Also, do you want to write a detector in c++? Or would a shell script suffice.

Comment: Well i'm learning both so an answer in either one is fine.I'm using windows 7 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows and c++:

### Memory Usage

Check out [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There's also an example at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682050%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` function will provide you a pointer to a [PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct which contains all of the memory usage information.

### CPU Usage

For CPU usage it's a little bit more difficult but the following stackoverflow question is related to that: [Getting current cpu usage in c++/windows for particular process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095994/getting-current-cpu-usage-in-c-windows-for-particular-process)

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Windows, you can ask the OS to take care of this for you -- create a [Process Job Object and configure limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx#job_limits_and_notifications).  The accounting features of the job object will let you track resource usage.

In Linux/Unix you would use `ulimit`.

*Don't* try to enforce this yourself.  If you have a runaway process, the most likely scenario is that your enforcer won't be scheduled in a timely manner to kill it.  You really want help from the kernel, and in particular the thread scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a process to monitor your other processes.

To do this in Linux in c++:

You can read from /proc/stat directly, or create a process to run 'ps' and parse its output to find processes with high %cpu. To create a process that runs ps, you'll need to use the 'fork' command.

Then you can call 'execvp' to call 'kill ', a function from .

Same idea goes for the bash script (this is probably quite a bit easier though).

Comment: `ps` is quite functional and makes sense to call.  OTOH `kill` is a pretty thin wrapper, might as well just call the `kill` function instead of execing the `kill` binary.