# Any Tool that watches the system performance and takes decisions

Tags: performance, debugging, operating-system, system, performancecounter

I am wondering if there is any tool (could be licensed/freeware/opensource) that does the monitoring of system performance parameters like CPU Usage, System Memory commit, handle count, ... and if the limit goes beyond the configured limit like lets say 90% of system memory commit is used , It could kill some of the configured processes ...

I investigated a couple of tools in sysinternals but all of them only does the monitoring and display the graphs but in none of the tools we could really configure to take decisions .... I havent gone through but probably any tool in windows performance tool kit has this sort of tool?.

Thx for the help in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows platform you could use **Performance Monitor** and **Resource Monitor**
both tools allow you to measure variations of CPU Usage, Memory and other parameters upon a time frame.

For more information regarding to these do refer the URLs below

[Using Resource Monitor](http://www.pcworld.com/article/241677/how_to_use_resource_monitor.html)

[How to Use Performance monitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/11/04/how-to-use-perfmon-in-windows-7.aspx)

On a Windows Server platform Performance Alerts can be triggered based on Threshold limits.
refer more at this URL.

[CPU Health Check](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/HealthCheck/Alerts.htm)

Comment: thanks for the reply .. i think these tools do a good job of monitoring and generating reports but there is no way i could configure them to perform a certain action like kill the high usage process or kill the process in a set of pre-configured list if the usage goes beyond certain limit .. Right?

Comment: Yes the above tools provide monitoring and alerting the user of CPU Usage it doesn't allow you to automatically kill a process. Do refer to these answers [Restarting processes](https://superuser.com/questions/16789/how-to-kill-restart-automatically-a-specific-windows-application-if-it-begins-ta) and [Kill a process if CPU Memory exeeds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527472/how-to-detect-a-process-cpu-memory-usage-and-kill-it-when-it-exceeds-a-certain-v)

Or you could use WMI Services in windows to implement a simple application to perform this task.

Comment: Thanks ... Those links have good information . I will investigate on the processTamer tool (It seems to only consider cpu usage), Are you aware of any commercial tool that could monitor a few more performance attributes(memory, cpu, handles...) and where in we could also configure what to do (restart/kill/log/...) .. If not, i would have to write one in c++ on windows... Appreciate your help till now ...