# Linux struct sysinfo update Windows

Tags: linux, windows, porting

Can anyone guide me how to fetch the information from windows to fill the structure  "struct sysinfo" (Linux Structure).

I think it require to call couple of API's to get the info and fill it.

Can anyone guide on this.

Comment: Did you consider instead using some libraries (Qt, Glib/Gtk, Poco, ...) providing a common abstracted API ?

Comment: You could use this [answer][1] as start point.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process