# How to determine CPU and memory consumption from Windows driver (aka kernel space)

Tags: c++, windows, driver, kernel-mode

The problem is actually quite simple to formulate: I need to know current CPU and memory consumption of the whole system from kernel-mode driver under Windows.
Of course, I have watched [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process) and tried this code. Results are not good: environment of Visual Studio 2013 for developing drivers does not know any headers from mentioned samples. E.g.:

```
#include "windows.h"

MEMORYSTATUSEX memInfo;
memInfo.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memInfo);
DWORDLONG totalVirtualMem = memInfo.ullTotalPageFile;
```

The code above is not compiling.
I carefully examined almost all "Kernel-Mode Driver Reference" in MSDN searching for similar functions and did not succeed.

So, does anyone know how to get same information from kernel-mode driver under Windows?

Or this is impossible? (This is quite strange, if true.)

Comment: You cannot use Win32 API in kernel mode. You have to use kernel API functions. Check WDK documentation.

Comment: The *documented* WDK functions focus on things that drivers should do.  Which is *not* creating an operating system inside an operating system.  NtQueryInformation() perhaps, it is undocumented and likely to be different across different Windows versions.

Comment: It finally appeared that implementing service process in userspace is the easiest solution: it periodically provides driver data about CPU and memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Those APIs aren't available to drivers, so it's not surprising that your attempt didn't build.

Memory management in kernel mode drivers is a lot more complicated than in user-mode applications. You should investigate [pool tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if there's a way to use the that to give you the info you want.