# How to get physical memory and cpu used by particular process in windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Hi this is my code that prints the physical memory used by some process displayed in bytes , when i am converting bytes into kb by google converter. The value shown in task manager for memory usage is less than output given by my code. Also i want to know the Cpu used by the same process ?
I found this question on Stack overflow,[CPU USAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process/%22CPU%20USAGE%22) that provides guidance in knowing cpu usage,but i want to know CPU usage for some Particular process id ,instead of current process as mentioned in my code, Can i achieve the same with the code provided.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
int main( void )
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
    DWORD processID = 4696;


    // Print information about the memory usage of the process.

    hProcess = OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                    PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                    FALSE, processID );
    if (NULL == hProcess)
        return 1;

    if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo( hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) )
    {

        printf( "\tWorkingSetSize: %u\n", pmc.WorkingSetSize );
    }

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CPU**

From the answer linked, you want to use your 'hProcess' handle instead of the 'self' handle from the sample.

Turn this:

```
self = GetCurrentProcess();
GetProcessTimes(self, &ftime, &ftime, &fsys, &fuser);
...
```

Into this:

```
GetProcessTimes(hProcess, &ftime, &ftime, &fsys, &fuser);
...
```

**Memory**

The Working Set is comprised of `Private` (heap, stack, etc) + `Shared` (typically dll/exe  code pages). What specific column in Task Manager (and what OS) are you referencing?

Comment: I am referring to Memory(Private Working set) and CPU columns of task manager.