# How to know information about how many resources does given process consume in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, cpu

Do any commands or extension in C++ exist to find out how much CPU time, operative memory, network resources and hard-disk does a given process (with given PID) consume?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process?rq=1

Comment: Those are strictly OS-specific things.

Comment: You can probably look it up in the `/proc` file-system. If you want for your own process then you could maybe use [`getrusage`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html).

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek There are standards, working for most linux systems.