# C++ invalid free memory report by sysinfo

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory

I'm trying to get the amount of physical memory currently used under Linux. I've followed the answer at [How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process) It appeared to work fine on my computer, but when deployed to DigitalOcean 512Mb server it started reporting some weird values.

According to `htop` system was using around 129Mb ram out of 490Mb available. Also here's the result of `free -m`.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           490        472         17          0        168        176
-/+ buffers/cache:        128        361
Swap:         1023          0       1023
```

Formula from the mentioned answer was `(sysinfo.totalram - sysinfo.freeram) * sysinfo.mem_unit`. It looks like I should also take the 'buffers' and 'cached' columns into account to get the correct value. So I wrote a simple test app to find out what's stored in the `sysinfo` structure.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main()
{
        struct sysinfo memInfo;
        sysinfo (&memInfo);

        long long int physMemUsed = memInfo.totalram - memInfo.freeram;
        physMemUsed *= memInfo.mem_unit;

        printf("totalRam %lld\n", (long long int)memInfo.totalram * memInfo.mem_unit / 1024 / 1024);
        printf("freeRam %lld\n", (long long int)memInfo.freeram * memInfo.mem_unit / 1024 / 1024);
        printf("sharedRam %lld\n", (long long int)memInfo.sharedram * memInfo.mem_unit / 1024 / 1024);
        printf("bufferRam %lld\n", (long long int)memInfo.bufferram * memInfo.mem_unit / 1024 / 1024);
        printf("totalSwap %lld\n", (long long int)memInfo.totalswap * memInfo.mem_unit / 1024 / 1024);
        printf("freeSwap %lld\n", (long long int)memInfo.freeswap * memInfo.mem_unit / 1024 / 1024);
        printf("totalHigh %lld\n", (long long int)memInfo.totalhigh * memInfo.mem_unit / 1024 / 1024);
        printf("freeHigh %lld\n", (long long int)memInfo.freehigh * memInfo.mem_unit / 1024 / 1024);
}
```

And here's the result:

```
totalRam 490
freeRam 17
sharedRam 0
bufferRam 168
totalSwap 1023
freeSwap 1023
totalHigh 0
freeHigh 0
```

It looks like `sysinfo.buffersram` corresponds to 'buffers' column of `free -m`, but what's the 'cached' value? What's the proper way to get the amount of used physical memory?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Yes, the OS will fill all available memory with file-cache/buffers, which can be disposed of should there be something more useful to put there - but you don't really want your system to sit there with a load of unused memory when it could be used for caching files, do you?

Comment: I want to get the amount of free physical memory, as reported by htop.

Comment: Does this help: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/fs/proc/meminfo.c. It's the source code to display cache system information.`cached = global_page_state(NR_FILE_PAGES) - total_swapcache_pages - i.bufferram;`

Comment: [`cached` seems to be the sum of the `Cached` and `Slab` value in `/proc/meminfo`.](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/v3.3.10/proc/sysinfo.c#L706)

Comment: `Cached` also includes all of `Shmem` and `tmpfs` usage, too. Note that those cannot be usually dropped in case more memory is needed so usable part of cached will be less than full `Cached`. See `MemAvailable` instead in `/proc/meminfo`.