# C++ - Find current CPU usage in Hertz (Windows)

Tags: c++, winapi, cpu-usage, pdh

**Current Situation:**
I'm looking to try and measure the current CPU utilisation of my system in Hertz.

I've had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64166/4343260) which addresses my question, however I cannot seem to make the code work.

This is my current **code** in `main.cpp` (from the answer):

```
#include <Pdh.h>
#include <PdhMsg.h>
#include <Windows.h>

static PDH_HQUERY cpuQuery;
static PDH_HCOUNTER cpuTotal;

void init()
{
    PDH_STATUS a = PdhOpenQuery(NULL, NULL, &cpuQuery);
    PDH_STATUS i = PdhAddCounter(cpuQuery, L"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", NULL, &cpuTotal);
    PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
}

double getCurrentValue()
{
    init();
    PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE counterVal;

    PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
    PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(cpuTotal, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, NULL, &counterVal);
    return counterVal.doubleValue;
}

int main()
{
    double CPUUsage = getCurrentValue();
}
```

**The Problem:**
The value returned from `getCurrectValue()` is zero.

**Related Observations:**
I have observed, that the values in `a` and `i` of type `PDH_STATUS` are both zero? I speculate that this could be related to my lack of a value in `CPUUsage`, although I'm not sure why the function wouldn't be returning properly into these values.

**Additional information:**
I haven't used PDH before.

Comment: If you've got 0 for the both status, and despite this, get zero CPU usage, it's probably because of the minimal delay required for diplaying cpu rates (see below the edit of my answer). .

Comment: Just a couple of clarifications: (1) CPU usage in cycles/sec doesn't really have any meaning in modern processors thus pdh gives % of processor; (2) the pdh commands provide estimates based upon OS activity and not the actual hardware performance counters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [`PdhAddCoutner()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is **language dependent**.  You should use **[`PdhAddEnglishCounter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** instead.

***EDIT:*** And you should have a minimal delay (500ms) between the query ran in the `init()` and the query in `getvalue()`.

**Additional explanations:**

Running your code on my windows 8.1 system,  it turned out that in `init()`,  the status `i` returned was `PDH_CSTATUS_NO_OBJECT`, which means that it didn't find the object "Processor(_Total)".

I first thought there was a typo, and verified the name of the object and the counter on [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938593.aspx).

By curiosity, I ran the original windows command `perfmon.exe` and noticed that all the objects and counter were translated in my native language. Running your code using the native language name of the counter gave me the correct result.

**About the timing constraint**

Once the language issue addressed, debugging step by step I got meaningful values of my CPU usage.  But once I removed the breakpoints, I got either 0 or 100.

So I dug a little further in this issue to find out on [microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262938) that % rates require some minimal delays between two consecutive queries. Once I added a `Sleep(1000)` at exit of init, I got again meaningful CPU usage values.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Needed windows definitions by following header */
#include <windef.h>
/* Windows performance data helper */
#include <Pdh.h>

/* Storage of PDH query and associated cpu counter */
struct cpu_counter{
    PDH_HQUERY query;
    PDH_HCOUNTER counter;
};

/* Initialize query & counter */
int cpu_counter_init(struct cpu_counter* pcc)
{
    if(PdhOpenQueryA(NULL, 0, &pcc->query) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return -1;
    if(PdhAddEnglishCounterA(pcc->query, "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", 0, &pcc->counter) != ERROR_SUCCESS || PdhCollectQueryData(pcc->query) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        PdhCloseQuery(pcc->query);
        return -2;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Fetch data from query and evaluate current counter value */
int cpu_counter_get(struct cpu_counter* pcc)
{
    PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE counter_val;
    if(PdhCollectQueryData(pcc->query) != ERROR_SUCCESS || PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(pcc->counter, PDH_FMT_LONG, NULL, &counter_val) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return -1;
    return counter_val.longValue;
}

/* Close all counters of query and query itself at the end */
void cpu_counter_close(struct cpu_counter* pcc)
{
    if(pcc->query != NULL)
    {
        PdhCloseQuery(pcc->query);
        pcc->query = NULL;
    }
}
```

No ugly statics, status checks, use of instances instead of global, minimal include, save even without unicode definition, solution of **Christophe** (plz rather upvote him than me) built-in.