# How can I find how much memory my application is used any any time in c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I have a program that runs a specific task over several files, so effectively it has a structure as follow:

```
std::vector<string> fileList=getFileList();
for(int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++)
{
       processFile(fileList[i]);
}
```

I am worried that there is a small memory leak in processFile function (this is relatively complex function which calls several other functions and uses several classes).

To check if I really have a memory leak in this function, like to measure the amount of memory that my application uses before and after the call to processFile and run it over a very large set of data and see how memory usage changes during processing.

Is there any way that I can measure the amount of memory that my application is using inside that application?

In the same way, can I find the amount of memory that each part of my application is using during run time?

Comment: Best way to detect memory leaks is to use a tool like valgrind. You also may run a static analysis tool, that often helpful to find bugs causing potential memory leaks.

Comment: Use valgrind with a *small* imput. It's very powerful, but it's also slow as hell :p

Comment: Can I use valgrind in windows? My application is a windows application

Comment: if you use visual studio:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want measure how much memory is using via above code at runtime u must calculate this:

> (# of element in fileList) * sizeof(string) + size of files in fileList

but if you want get all of your process memory usage in windows at runtime you can call **GetProcessMemoryInfo** API in your program and pass your process handle(**GetCurrentProcess()** API) to it,sample usage of this API:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682050.aspx

see complete response to your question via this link:

> [How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

Answer (score 0):

A common solution to detecting memory leaks and monitoring memory usage would be to run your program with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).