# Where can i find mach_host library for mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos

Where can I find `mach_host.h` library for mac OS X?
Because i can't find it on the web. 
I read the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process/1911863#1911863) by Michael Taylor in which `mach_host.h` library is used.

Comment: Ummmmm [Here](http://web.mit.edu/netbsd/src/sys/compat/mach/mach_host.h)

Comment: `find /usr -name mach_host.h`, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do software development under OSX, you need to go to the AppStore and install `Xcode` from Apple. That will have all the headers, libraries, compiler and linker and tools.

If you want to find that header file, you can then use this command:

```
find /Applications -name mach_host.h
```

There will be several answers, some for WatchOS, some for iOS and some for OSX. You need this one:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/mach/mach_host.h
```