# What's causing increase of memory usage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

When I'm running my code, my memory usage slowly increases despire the vector being cleared. The threads is explicitly joined and then vector is cleared. What's causing it to leak then? The leak occures to me while running program in release mode in Windows Visual Studio, the memory consumption went from 1 GB to 2 GB in 10 minutes. When I executed program from Linux console, no memory usage spiked, program finished successfully. In [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Y8M9fr6E3) program segfaults. So it behaves differently on 3 different platforms.

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
int mul(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
class Calc{ 
    std::vector<std::thread> vt = {};
public:
    Calc () {};
    ~Calc() noexcept {
        flush();
    };
    void flush() {
        for (auto& t : vt) { t.join(); }
        vt.clear();
    }
    template<typename F, typename... Ts>
    void addTask(F&& f, Ts&&... params) {
        vt.emplace_back(std::thread (std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Ts>(params)...) );
    }
};

int main()
{
    Calc calc;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            calc.addTask(mul, i, i * 2);
        }
        calc.flush();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation [vector.clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) ? std::vector's clear will not release memory. Either use [shrink_to_fit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) or swap with an empty vector  `std::swap(vt,{});`

Comment: There are no leak BTW, fragmentation might explain memory increase.

Comment: Jarod42, could you please explain what's causing fragmentation in your opinion?

Comment: Pepijn Kramer, thank you, it fixed the memory leak inside VS.

Comment: Given Pepijn's suggestion fixed the problem, what you have described here is **not** a memory leak.

Comment: It also doesn't explain the problem. A `clear()` on the vector resets the size to zero, and then reuses the memory for new members. Releasing the memory, only to immediately allocate it again 1000 times, will not decrease memory usage.

Comment: Compiler Explorer fails via an uncaught `std::system_error`. It probably struggle with creating 1 million threads.

Comment: Indeed looks like [memory fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35399992/4165552), because there is definitely no leak.

Comment: Depending on the actual work being done in your threads, you might need to fine-tune the number of threads to prevent excessive memory usage. Creating too many threads might overwhelm the system.