# Get CPU and RAM usage using C in mac

Tags: c, macos, cpu-usage

I need to get CPU and RAM usage just like when we use `top`. The problem with using `top` is that I need to submit the app in the mac store.

I found answers for C# or for Windows but I didn't find any for osx (I think).

So, how to find CPU and RAM usage?

Thank you!

Comment: A part (memory usage) of what you need is stated in the response of Michael Taylor on this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process

Comment: @M.Timtow I'll look into it. Thanks