# pytest: Is there a way to report memory usage of a test?

Tags: python, pytest

I checked the pytest documentation but I could not find anything relevant. I know `pytest --durations=0` will print out the runtime for all the tests. Is there a way to get pytest to also print out the peak memory usage consumed by a function? Otherwise, I can probably just use the decoration function below. But I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
from functools import wraps

    def mem_time(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            
            # Start of function
            r0 = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
            t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
    
            # Call function
            status = func(*args, **kwargs)
            
            # End of function
            r1 = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
            t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
            
            sys.stderr.write('{}: utime {} stime {} wall {}\n'.format(func.__name__,
                                                                      datetime.timedelta(seconds=r1.ru_utime - r0.ru_utime),
                                                                      datetime.timedelta(seconds=r1.ru_stime - r0.ru_stime),
                                                                      t1 - t0))
    
            sys.stderr.write('{}: mem {} MB ({} GB)\n'.format(func.__name__,
                                                              (r1.ru_maxrss - r0.ru_maxrss) / 1000.0,
                                                              (r1.ru_maxrss - r0.ru_maxrss) / 1000000.0))
            
            return status
        
        return wrapper
```

Comment: If interested, I can dig out some code, that shows you the memory occopied by the python process before and after the test.

However as Python does not always release memory that quickly it will not necessarily give you the right results, but it can be quite educational in some cases. Interested?

Comment: just checked my old code. I don't think it's any better than rusage. The code worked already for python2 though, which almost nobody cares about now.

`pip install psutil` to install and then `import os. psutil ;  rss =   psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss`

Answer (score 22):

**pytest-monitor** a new awesome plugins for pytest helps to monitor resources usage, timings, memory and so on. All metrics are stored in an sqlite database for post analysis

check out **pytest-monitor** from pypi or conda-forge:

- https://pypi.org/project/pytest-monitor/
- https://github.com/CFMTech/pytest-monitor

**Example**

```
$ pytest --db ./monitor.db

$ sqlite3 ./monitor.db

sqlite>.headers on

sqlite>.mode column
```

Then to show 10 most memory intensive tests:

```
sqlite> select ITEM, MEM_USAGE from TEST_METRICS ORDER BY MEM_USAGE DESC LIMIT 10;

ITEM|MEM_USAGE
test_api/test_data_get[/data/listdsh]|17.5703125
test_api/test_data_get[/data/listrecipients]|17.97265625
test_api/test_data_get[/data/getuserdetails]|18.125
```

`pytest-monitor` updates its SQLite database incrementally, so you might want to delete `monitor.db` file between test runs.

Note that if there is a memory leak in your code, the memory usage can increase test-by-test regardless of in which order you run them. Thus, you might want to run single tests, tests in different order and so on to locate the memory leak.

Comment: The downside is that [`pytest-monitor`](https://github.com/CFMTech/pytest-monitor) doesn't support [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) [yet](https://github.com/CFMTech/pytest-monitor/issues/39).

Comment: I updated this answer a bit with more details which might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

**Memory Profiling:**

There is no plugin to get memory profiling from the pytest (As far as I know).
Use the following link for memory profiling

https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler

Other references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43772305/9595032

**Cumulative times:**

https://pypi.org/project/pytest-profiling/

But to get Cumulative times of all calls to use plugin `pytest-profiling`

```
pip install pytest-profiling
```

Usage:

```
pytest -s -v [file_name] --profile
```

The output will look somewhat like this

```
Profiling (from /home/work/project/analytics/testing/TestCases/cloud/prof/combined.prof):
Wed Nov 20 12:09:47 2019    /home/work/project/analytics/testing/TestCases/cloud/prof/combined.prof

         437977 function calls (380211 primitive calls) in 3.866 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 683 to 20 due to restriction <20>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.866    3.866 runner.py:107(pytest_runtest_call)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.866    3.866 python.py:1457(runtest)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.866    3.866 hooks.py:275(__call__)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.866    3.866 manager.py:59(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.866    3.866 manager.py:65(_hookexec)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.866    3.866 callers.py:157(_multicall)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.866    3.866 python.py:188(pytest_pyfunc_call)
        1    0.001    0.001    3.866    3.866 test_abc.py:46(test_abc)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.865    3.865 test_abc.py:9(run_abc_test)
        1    0.001    0.001    3.854    3.854 dataAnalyzer.py:826(sanitize_data)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.773    3.773 Analyzer.py:563(Traffic)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.772    3.772 traffic.py:83(false_alarm_checks)
        3    0.000    0.000    3.767    1.256 api.py:60(get)
        3    0.000    0.000    3.765    1.255 api.py:135(_get_from_overpass)
        3    0.000    0.000    3.765    1.255 api.py:101(post)
        3    0.000    0.000    3.765    1.255 api.py:16(request)
        3    0.000    0.000    3.762    1.254 sessions.py:445(request)
        3    0.000    0.000    3.759    1.253 sessions.py:593(send)
        3    0.000    0.000    3.757    1.252 adapters.py:393(send)
        3    0.000    0.000    3.755    1.252 connectionpool.py:447(urlopen)
```

Comment: pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --profile

Comment: is the pytest-profiling installed correctly?