# Current memory usage display is always ~14MB more than task manager

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory, taskmanager

I'm currently using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process/64166#64166), with some slight modifications as suggested in the comments. However, no matter how many objects I allocate in memory, the listed memory usage is always ~14MB more than what task manager lists. Why could this be?

```
std::stringstream ss;

PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*)&pmc, sizeof(pmc));
SIZE_T physMemUsedByMe = pmc.WorkingSetSize;

ss << "\nMEM: " << (physMemUsedByMe / 1024 / 1024) << " MB";    

debugText.setString(ss.str());
```

**Results on a normal build:**

*debugText:*

[image: debugText]

*Task Manager:*

[image: Task Manager:]

*Resource Monitor:*

[image: Resource Monitor]

**Results when allocating 10,000 dummy objects:**

*debugText:*

[image: debugText]

*Task Manager:*

[image: Task Manager]

*Resource Monitor:*

[image: Resource Monitor]

**EDIT:**

After using Resource Monitor (perfmon) as the comments suggested, I found that the column for `Working Set` matches the memory-listing function I'm using. However, I'm still perplexed as to why there's a ~14MB difference between the `Working Set` column and the `Private` column (the latter of which is what Task Manager appears to use). Why is this the case?

Comment: Post compilable code.

Comment: Task Manager offers many different memory measurements.  Please specify one you're citing (give the complete column header).

Comment: this is under windows 10 only ? try use `VM_COUNTERS_EX2.PrivateWorkingSetSize` and compare with data from taskmgr. however on win 8.1 and early your code must show the same results as taskmgr

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I'm using the Memory column from the default task manager on Windows 10. "Total physical memory reserved by individual processes"

Comment: @TrampolineTales - you say about *working set* or *private working set* or *shared working set* column ?

Comment: what is under Total physical memory reserved by individual processes" is same as `private working set` under details tab(private working set), but in * 1.024. in one place used 1000bytes as kb, in another 1024

Comment: Don't use task manager as a debug tool, it is not intended for that.  It handles shared and paged out memories in ways that aren't always obvious.  Use perfmon, if you must.

Comment: @Donnie perfmon appears to have more information, thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the question with perfmon stats.

Comment: Shared DLLS don't get loaded into every process space.  They get mapped in.  That's the difference you're seeing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Task Manager does not use the Win32 API `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` function.  It uses the NT API `ZwQueryInformationProcess()` function, setting the `ProcessInformationClass` parameter to `ProcessVmCounters`.

Beginning in Windows 10, the following structure is defined (in `ntddk.h`):

```
typedef struct _VM_COUNTERS_EX2 {
    VM_COUNTERS_EX CountersEx;
    SIZE_T PrivateWorkingSetSize;
    ULONGLONG SharedCommitUsage;
} VM_COUNTERS_EX2, *PVM_COUNTERS_EX2;
```

Task Manager uses `VM_COUNTERS_EX2` similar to the following code:

```
VM_COUNTERS_EX2 vm;
ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessVmCounters, &vm, sizeof(vm), 0);
```

The value it shows for the "Memory(private working set)" column is the `vm.PrivateWorkingSetSize` field.

It looks like a Win32 API analog for this does not exist at this time.  How you can see this:

```
typedef struct _VM_COUNTERS_EX {
    SIZE_T PeakVirtualSize;
    SIZE_T VirtualSize;// note this !!
    ULONG PageFaultCount;
    SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
    SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
    SIZE_T QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PrivateUsage;
} VM_COUNTERS_EX;
```

The `VM_COUNTERS_EX` base of `VM_COUNTERS_EX2` is very near `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` but not exact (there are no `[Peak]VirtualSize`) members).  `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` internally calls `ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessVmCounters)` and then copies the `VM_COUNTERS_EX` to `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX`.

---

In Task Manager on Windows 10, the "Memory(physical memory reserved by individual processes)" column shows `PrivateWorkingSet` (in increments of 1024 bytes).  This same value is shown under the "Details" tab (private working set).  For an unknown reason, that value is shown in increments of 1000 bytes, so the real value is always 1.024 times higher.

But you use the "total" working set - `WorkingSetSize` - which is the sum of the "private" and "shared" working sets (you need the add columns to the Details tab to view this, by default only the private memory is shown).  So, there is a constant difference in the result (14 MB) - this is the "shared" working set (usually common DLLs, like `ntdll.dll`, `kerner32.dll`, `kernelbase.dll`, etc).  This difference does not change when you allocate memory (10,000 dummy objects).  The "private" working set grows, but the "shared" working set remains unchanged (because no new DLLs are loaded/unloaded).

If you want to show memory like Task Manager does, use the `PrivateWorkingSetSize` member of `VM_COUNTERS_EX2` from the NT API.  If you cannot use that, then you will have different results than Task Manager.

If you do not like the NT API, or do not understand it, this is not my problem (or maybe somebody can *now* get the `PrivateWorkingSetSize` by using some "documented" API?).  If Task Manager uses the NT API, this is also not my choice.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I don't understand what you're saying with the way your answer is structured.

Comment: @TrampolineTales - i try say that you need use `ZwQueryInformationProcess(,ProcessVmCounters,)` with `VM_COUNTERS_EX2` structure and use `PrivateWorkingSetSize` member if you want got same result as windows manager (all this only on win10) - what here unclear ?