# C++ Query private working set size using WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to query the private working set size of a given process only using WinAPI - no WMI. I can already query the memory information using `GetProcessMemoryInfo()`, but this only contains the working set size, not the **private** working set size.

I've found several approaches but all of them involve WMI, which I would like to avoid using. Also found comments suggesting that you can query memory information using `VirtualQuery` and calculate the value yourself, but non of them describe how, and documentation on this is just awful.

Comment: Maybe `QueryWorkingSet`?

Comment: Already looked into that, but documentation on that is just as bad. It's absolutely unclear to me how I can calculate the private working set size based on the returned  [working set blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/ns-psapi-_psapi_working_set_ex_block).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42986966/6401656

Comment: But is it possible to call `ZwQueryInformationProcess` outside of a kernel driver/library? Because if not then this is not a solution to me. I was going to mention no NT calls, but I'm not sure if there's a way to get around that.

Comment: If you want to rule out all viable solutions, then you can just give up

Comment: `ZwQueryInformationProcess` this is **user mode** api exported from *ntdll.dll*. call it like any usual api