# How to get memory usage of an application programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I want to get memory usage of my application (Windows, Win7, x64) from within it, programmatically. I tried using the API `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` but I'm not sure about the returned values.

What I would like to get are:

- the total memory used by the app (*RAM + page file*)
- the total physical memory used by the app (*RAM only*).

My goal is to track memory leak(s) by executing repetitive tasks from within my application and monitoring/logging the evolution of the used memory.

**Note**: Currently I'm using `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS::PageFileUsage` for total memory and `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS::WorkingSetSize` for the physical (RAM) memory. I think this is not the right way to get what I want.

Comment: not think that memory-leaks can be effective found by this. and here may be most useful be Virtual memory Size used by process (from *VM_COUNTERS*, but this member is dropped when copied to *PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS* )

Answer (score 0):

I refered to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process) and follow the recommendations. From `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX::PrivateUsage` I got the same values as from `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS::PageFileUsage`.

I assume the solution I used and described in my question is the right one.