# Programmatically retrieve peak virtual memory of a process

Tags: c++, linux, macos, memory, freebsd

I'm trying to find out the *peak virtual memory* of my running process on Linux, macOS and FreeBSD.

I'm focusing on peak virtual memory as this is a relevant measure of the peak memory usage of my process at any given point, beyond the limits of physical RAM (what peak RSS would provide).

In the spirit of [How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process) I'm planning to use this post to compile solutions for these three platforms (I'll be happy to extend it to more platforms if you have working code to provide).

#### Windows

On Windows, the following appears to return the same values as [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer):

```c++
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
GetProcessMemoryInfo(
    GetCurrentProcess(),
    reinterpret_cast<PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*>(&pmc),
    sizeof(pmc));
return pmc.PeakPagefileUsage;
```

#### Linux

Is parsing the output of `/proc/self/status` the best/only option on Linux? Do all Linux flavors return the same information formatted in the exact same way?

For reference, here's a sample output on Ubuntu:

```
root@appleseedhq:~# cat /proc/self/status
Name:   cat
State:  R (running)
Tgid:   12975
Ngid:   0
Pid:    12975
PPid:   12938
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    0       0       0       0
Gid:    0       0       0       0
FDSize: 256
Groups: 0
VmPeak:     7220 kB
VmSize:     7220 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:       608 kB
VmRSS:       608 kB
VmData:      176 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:        44 kB
VmLib:      1924 kB
VmPTE:        40 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        1
(more stuff...)
```

The line of interest here appears to be

```
VmPeak:     7220 kB
```

Any simpler, faster and less brittle solution?

#### macOS

On macOS I thought that using `task_info()` with `TASK_BASIC_INFO` or `MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO` would do the job, i.e.

```c++
#ifdef MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO
    struct mach_task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t info_count = MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;

    if (task_info(
            mach_task_self(),
            MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO,
            (task_info_t)&info,
            &info_count) != KERN_SUCCESS)
        return 0;
#else
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t info_count = TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;

    if (task_info(
            mach_task_self(),
            TASK_BASIC_INFO,
            (task_info_t)&info,
            &info_count) != KERN_SUCCESS)
        return 0;
#endif
```

Unfortunately, while close, it doesn't look like I can get *peak* virtual memory of a process, only *current* virtual memory usage (in `info.virtual_size`, in bytes).

#### FreeBSD

Again, on FreeBSD I thought that [`getrusage()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getrusage&sektion=2) would provide the info but it doesn't appear to have anything about peak virtual memory.

Comment: Have a look at `/usr/bin/time -l` on a Mac.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That command doesn't appear to return peak virtual memory, only peak RSS.

Comment: you can use libproc (part of procps)