# How can I get the size in bytes allocated on data memory segment?

Tags: c++, windows

Is there any way to get the number of bytes allocated in the data memory segment by a C++ program during debug-time? I know how to track general memory consumption and heap allocation, but this is something I have never done before.

I am looking for either a code solution or some form of Visual Studio analyzing utility.

Comment: Something like Allocation hooks? Visual C++ has machinery for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019,  https://github.com/Microsoft/VCSamples/tree/master/VC2010Samples/crt/crt_dbg2

Comment: whats a "data memory segment"?

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process

Comment: Helps a lot, thanks! @JorgePerez