# Determine CPU, Memory, Disk Usage data for C++ Application

Tags: c++, clion

I've an application which runs on linux where I need to gather the performance statistics (CPU usage, Memory usage, Disk usage etc) from inside the application itself.

As I observed there are two methods to achieve this.

First one is to execute a tool like pidstat or sar from the c++ code and process the result and gather information and save them in a database
Second method is to follow the method mentioned in below ticket.

[How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

I need to know the recommended way of doing this. I might need to gather around 10 performance statistics fields (like CPU Usage, Memory Usage, Disk Usage etc).

Comment: This is not a duplicate because I'm asking for a recommendation

Comment: questions asking for recommendations are off-topic because they attract opinionated answers

Comment: @kmdreko then how to get the recommendations? could you please guide me

Comment: A different Stack Exchange site such as [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) might be a better place for this question.