# Obtain memory usage of a C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I want to obtain memory usage of a C++ project in Microsoft Visual Sutio 2019 on Win 7 64 bit.
I followed the post
[How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process/64166#64166)

By using this code inside my main function:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "psapi.h"

int main()
{
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
    GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*)&pmc, sizeof(pmc));
    SIZE_T virtualMemUsedByMe = pmc.PrivateUsage;
    // My function here
}
```

And when I change my function parameters to increase workloads, the result of `virtualMemUsedByMe` is always 2516k.

What is wrong here with me?

Comment: Memory isn't equivalent to CPU usage. Maybe your workload increased but the memory used remains the same.

Comment: @Aplet123 But in Resource Monitor I can see the memory usage is increased when I increased workloads. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Do you really call your function *after* measuring memory usage?