# Programatically get linux process memory usage inside a container

Tags: linux, memory

I would like to programmatically acquire the memory usage of the current running process (from within that process). The following SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process) explains in detail how this can be achieved. However, what is suggested in that post is to acquire these values from `proc` pseudo filesystem. Since I want this to work properly also if the process is running in a container (not necessarily a docker container), I am not sure will this approach yield correct results.

The reason for my concerns are various articles ([Why top and free inside container show wrong memory](https://ops.tips/blog/why-top-inside-container-wrong-memory/), [Memory inside Linux containers](https://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/)) that explain how information in `proc` is not aware of cgroups and memory limits imposed on the container. What I want to acquire is the memory used by my process, not total/available memory, so since my container process is in reality running on the host OS, my assumption is that values `VmSize`, `VmRss` and `VmPeak` from `/proc/self/status` will still show correct values.

So my questions are:

- Is my assumption that `/proc/self/status` can still reliably be used correct, or am I overlooking something?
- If using `/proc/self/status` is not reliable, is there some better way (maybe the corresponding cgroup of the process holds this information)?

Comment: use docker stats to the container resources usage and the limit

Comment: @c4f4t0r Can this be achieved programmatically and per single process? I am not interested in total memory usage within the container.

Comment: is good habit to have only a process in a containers, unless is a whale :)