# Printing size_t using cout gives uncanny output

Tags: c++, cout, size-t

I am trying to print size_t values using cout. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  size_t blah = 15;
  cout << blah +" gibberish";
  return 0;
}
```

The output I get is this: `D`.

Thanks for the help! :)

*I am trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process) to print memory usage.
*Also, what exactly is unit of size_t?
*I tried posting `cout<<blah +" bytes";` which gives me a telephone Unicode emoji (U+0007 :  BELL [BEL]) as the output but  stackoverflow refuses to display it .

Comment: clang has a nice warning for that: https://wandbox.org/permlink/lpowUUxwN3iiLbnh (unfortunately, no warning in gcc)

Comment: "_what exactly is size unit of size_t_"  `sizeof(std::size_t)`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, there is a trick, you can trigger the warning by using optimization -O2 or -O3.

Comment: Accessing the `" gibberish"` C literal string at position 15 is past the end of the C literal string, and results in **undefined behavior**.  The behavior observed is exactly the sort of undefined behavior that I'd expect, because I expect that *anything that happens* is expected for an invalid program.

Comment: Note that this is not directly related to `std::size_t`. Any integer type would show the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`blah +" bytes"` is adding an integer to a pointer (converted from array of `char`), so the pointer is moved to invalid place.

You should do

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  size_t blah = 15;
  cout << blah << " bytes";
  return 0;
}
```

instead. (use `<<` instead of `+`: print the number and string one-by-one instead of trying to concatenate them beforehand)