# this declaration has no storage class or type specifierC/C++

Tags: c++, linux, memory, cpu

I am trying to implement this code from
[How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

When I write

```
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "sys/sysinfo.h"

struct sysinfo memInfo;

sysinfo(&memInfo);
long long totalVirtualMem = memInfo.totalram;
//Add other values in next statement to avoid int overflow on right hand side...
totalVirtualMem += memInfo.totalswap;
totalVirtualMem *= memInfo.mem_unit;
```

I receive an error message on

```
sysinfo(&memInfo);
```

Error Message

```
this declaration has no storage class or type specifierC/C++
```

Comment: You can only call functions inside other functions. And you need `int main()` function as the entry point of your program.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/CPP/default.asp

Comment: The example code in the linked does have this error.  I guess it was meant to be just a snippet where you would insert the block  into your function and put the includes at the top of your file.

Comment: You need to write it like this: https://godbolt.org/z/Knd57G99n

Comment: Although I suspect some to downvote this question as being too trivial of a problem. I think its reasonable given the example code in an answer did have this error. I think this warrants a small answer by @Ari

Comment: Seems like a good demonstration that one shouldn't just copy code from stackoverflow. (In this case there is an error. It could be even worse if it was silently behaving in unintended ways.) Code shown in answers should only be used to further ones own understanding of the issue and the solution. The linked answer clearly expects that the reader has some understanding of C and C++ and will use it to get an idea of the API to apply accordingly.

Comment: @user17732522: It probably also demonstrates that it's a better practice that fellow stackoverflow members should provide more accurate answers to make them useful to a larger audience :)

Comment: What do you expect `sysinfo(&meminfo)` to do?  Its similar to this: `int word; int(&word);`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If it was written inside a function block, that would be correct. There is a `sysinfo` function and a `sysinfo` structure. The function fills the structure. The name of the former hides the latter in C++, which is why the `struct` keyword in the declaration is required also in C++. (It is a C API where the name hiding wouldn't be an issue.)